# What is Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets package?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.1

When I create a project in .NET Core 2.1. These is the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets` is already included in my project. I can't find any documents for that.
Can anyone tell me what is it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets` package is added in VS2017 when Docker Support is selected for the project. It enabled Visual Studio Tooling for Docker file.

Removing this package may give you errors if you intend to Dockerize your project/application in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: So, no problem If I remove it, and build the docker image my project by powershell/cmd. Is this right?

Comment: yes, exactly. The package is required only when you want the Docker support within Visual Studio.